# ASP.NET Web Api trouble with getting token cross-origin

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api

I'm having some trouble logging in to my Web Api from my frontend (Node.js and Ajax) with cross-origin stuff. I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:61102/Token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

This problem only occurs when I try to call /Token to log in. I can access other routes and Register perfectly. Heres my code:

Startup.cs:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    ConfigureAuth(app);

    WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    app.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

Startup.Auth.cs:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

    // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
    // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
    PublicClientId = "self";
    OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
        Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
        AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
        // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
        AllowInsecureHttp = true
    };

    // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
    app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
}
```

And I have put `context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });` into `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)` in the ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs

I have tried searching for an answer for a very long time, and have stumbled upon alot of different answers, which did not work for me. Not sure whats wrong.

**Update** - Added my ajax script

```
import {URL} from '../constants/AuthConstants';
import request from 'reqwest';
import history from './HistoryService';

let router = null;

class AuthService {

    login(email, password) {
        console.log(URL.LOGIN);
        var grant_type = 'password';
        return request({
            url: URL.LOGIN,
            method: 'POST',
            crossOrigin: true,
            content-Type
            data: {
                grant_type, email, password
            },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log("Yay! Login", response);
            },
            error: function(response) {
                console.log("Error! Login", response);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try putting  var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors); in the  Configuration method?

Comment: @Yousuf yeah, it doesn't work. Should it be there though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holy crap I got it working. Not sure if it is good or the correct way to do it though (probably not, but it works). What I did was I deleted `app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);` and all other enable cors stuff in my code in a furious rage and added this to my web.config inside `<system.webServer>`:

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:8080"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

I will mark this as the answer because it works, but since I am unsure if its the correct way to solve this problem, please tell me if it is and I will change the "correct answer" thing.

**EDIT** - Correct way to do it

Using the methods above I was able to register and login, but not able to perform other calls like to "api/values/1" for example (because it sent an 'OPTIONS' before sending a 'GET' or something, which I didn't want to make a handler for). What I did was changed back to some old code I had tried many times, but not worked before.

I deleted the httpProtocol thing from Web.config.

I updatet WebApiConfig to this:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

and in ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs in the GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(), I added this line to the top of the function:

```
context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
```

This is some of the exact same code which I had tried many times before, but this time I have no idea what made it work. I logged of my computer and when I came back and tried it, it suddenly worked. There is some voodo stuff going on here, but this is probably the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You're using CORS a little differently than I have in the past. I've done the following many times with relative success.

Add a reference in your WebApi project to `System.Web.Cors` and add the below to your `Register` method inside your `WebApiConfig.cs` file:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.SetCorsPolicyProviderFactory(new CorsPolicyFactory());
    config.EnableCors();
    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );                     
}
```

More in depth tutorials can be found here:

http://tostring.it/2014/03/04/how-to-use-CORS-with-ASPNET-WebAPI-2/

http://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html

Comment: Hey! this is what I tried first, and it worked for everything except the /token endpoint which gave me the error. This all works perfectly in Postman though, and I am able to get an access-key from /token. It did the same as my code above.

Comment: Damn, really? I'll keep digging.

Comment: Great, thanks. Also, could it probably be something with my ajax request? Im sending it from a service in my react app. I have updatet the question with my javascript.