# I can't get the token in a WebApi due to a problem with CORS

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have the following problem: I have an Api created in .Net Framework 4.6.2 and an external provider who is developing a frontend in React tries to connect to it.

Every time you request a token you get a CORS error. The other requests work correctly

*Cross-origin request blocked: Same-origin policy does not allow reading remote resources at https://xx.xx.xx.xx:88/Token. (Reason: Unsuccessful CORS request). Status code: (null).*

I have tried all of these things without success:

- Enable Cors in WebApiConfig

  ```
       // Configuración de CORS
       var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
       config.EnableCors(cors);
  ```
- Enable headers in IIS

[image]

- I have tried several clauses in the web.config

```html
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Authorization" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
  
  <cors enabled="true">
      <add origin="*">
        <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true" />
        <allowMethods>
            <add method="GET" />
            <add method="HEAD" />
            <add method="POST" />
            <add method="PUT" /> 
            <add method="DELETE" />
            <add method="OPTION" />             
        </allowMethods>
     </add>      
    </cors>
```

- I have tried generating self-signed certificates

[image]

The requests come with the following headers

[image]

I think I've tried everything I've found on other sites and I can't solve the problem. Has anyone managed to solve it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error only appears when I make the request from the browser, if I replicate the request in Postman everything works fine.

Comment: I  have tried the solution in this post, but not work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33902552/asp-net-web-api-trouble-with-getting-token-cross-origin

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: how is the token being sent?

Comment: Implementing JWT authentication. I use app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions); in ConfigureAuth Section